# Add new node to existing node in JavaTree using Java

Tags: java, tree

I have a already created java tree. Now I want to add new node to existing node in this Java tree. This existing node can be any where in the tree.

My tree nodes are included in a HashMap and each node have key(String) and value(Double). I know its key and value. So, how to add this node to correct existing node?

```
  DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new NodeInfor(check, 0.45));  

            nodeReg.put(check, newNode);
            ?????.add(newNode);
```

In above code for ????? what I need to used? Existing node is I already created.But  In this point I select it randomly and I know only its key and value.

If I want to create a separate another JavaTree after adding this new node,

```
                tree = new JTree(root); ------------------????
                add(tree);
                this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                this.setTitle("Sub JTrees");
                this.pack();
                this.setVisible(true);
```

in above code,  `tree = new JTree(root);` what I need to add for `root`?

UPDATE:
More coding part:

```
        //create root
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new NodeInfor(keys.get(0), values.get(0)));
        // create the child nodes
        DefaultMutableTreeNode aNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new NodeInfor(keys.get(1), values.get(1)));
        DefaultMutableTreeNode bNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new NodeInfor(keys.get(2), values.get(2)));

           nodeReg.put(keys.get(0), root);
           nodeReg.put(keys.get(1), aNode);
           nodeReg.put(keys.get(2), bNode);

           root.add(aNode);
           root.add(bNode);
           -----------
           -----------
             ---------
           ---------
            tree = new JTree(root);
            add(tree);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setTitle("First JTree");
            this.pack();
            this.setVisible(true);
             ---------
             ----------
             ----------
           DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new NodeInfor(check, 0.45));  

            nodeReg.put(check, newNode);
            ?????.add(newNode);-----------------?????????

            tree = new JTree(???????????);------------??????
            add(tree);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setTitle("Sub JTree");
            this.pack();
            this.setVisible(true);
            }
```

I want to add new node to `keys.get(1), values.get(1)` . So how to add and display new tree again?

Comment: Can you post your full tree code?

Comment: @user3747720  I updated my question with some more coding. If my tree is become big how to add new node to existing node (existing one can be in middle or anywhere in the tree, I know its key and value) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope `nodeReg` is map, So you can get `anode`  by callling get method and passing `keys.get(1)` as key.

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode newNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(new NodeInfor(check, 0.45));  
nodeReg.put(check, newNode);
DefaultMutableTreeNode node = nodeReg.get(keys.get(1));
node.add(newNode); //add new node to anode
tree = new JTree(root);
```

Now this tree will be having four nodes

```
root,aNode,bNode,newNode
```

Comment: If you want more clear view then post code of DefaultMutableTreeNode, So that I can get add method.